Integrating Allure Reporting into Playwright Tests Azure Pipeline
I am practicing with Playwright automation and learning to integrate it with CI/CD pipelines in Azure.
I have managed to create a Repo and Pipeline in Azure that runs my Playwright code, but I am a little stuck on getting Allure reporting to work
This is my yaml file for the azure pipeline, I have added in the Allure steps as follows:
trigger:
- none

pool: customagent
  

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
- script: npm ci
  displayName: 'npm ci'
- script: npx playwright install --with-deps
  displayName: 'Install Playwright browsers'
- script: npm run regression
  displayName: 'Run Playwright tests' 
- script: npx playwright test --reporter=line,allure-playwright
  displayName: 'Use Allure reports'
- script: npm run GenReport
  displayName: 'Generate Allure reports and clean'
- task: qameta.allure-azure-pipelines.PublishAllureReport.PublishAllureReport@1
  inputs:
    testResultsDir: 'allure-results'
    reportName: 'Report'
  env:
    CI: 'true'

This is what is in my Playwright package.json file, I have added custom scripts:
{
  "name": "playwright",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "regression": "npx playwright test",
    "GenReport": "npx allure generate ./allure-results --clean",
    "Open Allure Reports": "allure open ./allure-report"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.43.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.7.1",
    "@zerostep/playwright": "^0.1.5",
    "allure-playwright": "^2.15.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^10.4.0"
  }
}

When I run the pipeline, it ends up opening the html reporter and then remains on that step. I'm really not sure what to do from this point, I have installed the necessary marketplace extension for the Allure report viewer, which I used in my yaml file


I can reproduce the same issue when running the npx playwright test.

To solve this issue, you can add an Pipeline variable: CI:true at the root level of the Pipeline.
For example:
trigger:
- none

pool: customagent

variables:
  CI: true 

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
- script: npm ci
  displayName: 'npm ci'
- script: npx playwright install --with-deps
  displayName: 'Install Playwright browsers'
- script: npm run regression
  displayName: 'Run Playwright tests' 
- script: npx playwright test --reporter=line,allure-playwright
  displayName: 'Use Allure reports'
  continueOnError: true
- script: npm run GenReport
  displayName: 'Generate Allure reports and clean'
  continueOnError: true
- task: qameta.allure-azure-pipelines.PublishAllureReport.PublishAllureReport@1
  inputs:
    testResultsDir: 'allure-results'
    reportName: 'Report'
  continueOnError: true
  env:
    CI: 'true'

Or you can add environment variable to the script task:
For example:
- script: npm run regression
  displayName: 'Run Playwright tests' 
  env:
    CI: true

Then it will continue to run the next tasks.

Thank you, it has continued the steps with the additional variable added., but exits with a cmd.exe exited with code '1' error and also skips the steps to do with generating and publishing the Allure reports,
I saw that I was running the playwright tests twice, once in the package.json script, then again in the yaml, with the addition of the allure script, so I removed it from yaml and updated the package.json and then ran it again. I thought this might fix it, but I am continuing to see the same error

@Amar you can add the field:  continueOnError: true in the next script task(generate report task). Then it will run the next tasks instead of skipping them

@Amar you can check the update in my answer

Thank you, it continues onto the next step now. I will read up on yaml files to further my understanding
